# Why this Python code is saving me the concat dataframes so messy?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm working with a json file of 146 000 lines, I need to plot some columns of this information. It is really time consuming, saving all of this in  dataframe at  once, so I started to work with read_csv an assigning a chunk size, as you can see in my code, because I do not need all the columns, I'm creating a new dataframe with columns I really need, and then making a concat and saving to a csv file. Once I run my code is saving me not in order,you can see in the picture that the first time works perfectly, and also know that this code shoul be repeating the same first line over and over, but why is showing the first chunk like this?? Please can you help?? At this point any idea is a big help! Thanks!!

```
for i in pd.read_json('info_img_havana.json',chunksize=10,lines=True):
df=i.id.to_frame()
df2=json_normalize(i.dates)['taken'].to_frame()
df3=pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)
```

once I print df3 is giving me this:

[image]

part of the json file

[image]

Comment: I'm asking about the NaN. It should be showing me all chunks like the first, right?

Comment: Can you please share some lines from the data to see the original format and be able to reproduce your issue (make sure to remove the sensitive information before sharing)?

Comment: I just shared a piece of the json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, the problem was the Frame index that is continuous, so when you create a new DataFrame, it takes its own index.
You can check it by adding the following code

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index_chunk':i.index,'index_df':df.index})
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Done!!Was a problem with the index ..this code works:

```
for i in pd.read_json('info_img_havana.json', chunksize=10, lines=True):
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(d=json_normalize(i.dates)['taken']))
    df.set_index(i.index,inplace=True)
```